# Need help appending a hidden field based on dynamic, multiple input boxes that will always be different

Tags: jquery, appendchild

Please help, I am at my wits end.

I have a form, and in that form, a user can enter a number for several different sizes:

Size 6: (text box) 
Size 7: (text box)
Size 8: (text box)

When the user enters a quantity of say "2" for size six, I am using jquery to create input elements (2 of them) for each quantity (so a total of 4 boxes.)

These four boxes allow the user to enter a name and a date for each of the quantities ordered.

I then need to collect and store ALL values of all of these textboxes into ONE hidden field which gets submitted with the form.

Example of the code is as follows:

The jquery part (this is for SIZE 6)

```
function generate6() {

    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("mesize-6").value);
    var ch = document.getElementById("ch");


   document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = "";

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.value = 'Size 6 Left Text (10 chars. max)';
        input.type = "text";
        input.name = "textboxes6left";
        input.style.color = "gray";
        input.style.width = "208px";
        input.style.marginRight = "10px";
        input.style.marginBottom = "10px";

        var input2 = document.createElement("input");
        //var input2 = document.createElement("<input type='text' NAME='mego'>");
        input2.value = 'Size 6 Right Text (10 chars. max)';
        input2.name = "textboxes6right";
        input2.style.color = "gray";
        input2.style.width = "208px";
        input2.style.marginRight = "0px";
        input2.style.marginBottom = "10px";
        ch.appendChild(input);
        ch.appendChild(input2);


    }
}
```

As you can see, the textboxes will all end up having the same name for each size, no matter if only one quantity is entered or 7.

The hidden field has an id = "validate" and a name = "customtext"

I need to add all of the dynamic text box values into this hidden field.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: I'm unclear on the exact problem you're trying to solve. Does the code you provide produce an error? Or do you not know how to add the text-box values to this hidden input? Is the code above supposed to be doing both of these things?

Comment: I have tried multiple ways of accomplishing this.  The form contains a hidden field called "customtext". The code above creates dynamic text boxes based on the value a user submits into quantity fields.

So the form has one quantity for for size six, one for seven, one for eight.  User enters 2 for size six and four new boxes pop up for user to enter a custom name and date for each quantity of size six.  The four boxes are named as above: textboxes6left textboxes6left textboxes6right textboxes6right.  I need to get the values entered into these boxes to pass into the hidden field.

Comment: You already know how to get the value of a field. Which part is giving you trouble? Does this solve it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName